# How am I able to shutdown the system when I don't have SeShutdownPrivilege

Tags: windows, privileges

Users in Windows can be granted various [**privileges**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Privileges determine the type of system operations that a user account can perform. An administrator assigns privileges to user and group accounts. Each user's privileges include those granted to the user and to the groups to which the user belongs.

There are currently 35 privileges. Some of the more interesting ones are:

- **SeSystemtimePrivilege**: Required to modify the system time.
- **SeTimeZonePrivilege**: Required to adjust the time zone associated with the computer's internal clock
- **SeBackupPrivilege**: This privilege causes the system to grant all read access control to any file, regardless of the access control list (ACL) specified for the file.
- **SeCreatePagefilePrivilege**: Required to create a paging file.
- **SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege**: Required to shut down a system using a network request.
- **SeDebugPrivilege**: Required to debug and adjust the memory of a process owned by another account.

But the one I'm interested in is:

- **SeShutdownPrivilege**: Required to shut down a local system.

I noticed that I don't actually **have** this privilege. From an elevated command prompt:

```
>whoami /priv

PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                  Description                               State
=============================== ========================================= ========
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege        Adjust memory quotas for a process        Disabled
SeSecurityPrivilege             Manage auditing and security log          Disabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege        Take ownership of files or other objects  Disabled
   ...
SeShutdownPrivilege             Shut down the system                      Disabled
   ...
```

This is confirmed when using **Process Explorer** to examine the security token of an elevated process running as me:

[image]

And yet I *can* shut down the system. Why?

## The Group Policy says I should have it

If you use the Local Security Policy editor snapin (`secpol.msc`), you can see that I *should* have the privilege:

- secpol.msc

  - Security Settings
  - Local Policies
  - User Rights Assignment
  - Shut down the system

    [image]

The *Explaination* of the privilege:

> Shut down the system
>
> This security setting determines which users who are logged on locally
>   to the computer can shut down the operating system using the Shut Down
>   command. Misuse of this user right can result in a denial of service.
>
> Default on Workstations: Administrators, Backup Operators, Users.
>
> Default on Servers: Administrators, Backup Operators.
>
> Default on Domain controllers: Administrators, Backup Operators,
>   Server Operators, Print Operators.

I'm a **User**. Sometimes I'm an **Administrator**, and other times I'm a **NotAdministrator**.

Perhaps the question should be why **don't** I have the privilege.

But the reality is that I don't have the privilege; and yet when locally logged in I can shut down the local system.

Why?

---

@Mehrdad had a good answer, that he deleted, which i think deserves attention and answers the question nicely and succinctly:

> You **have** the privilege. It's merely disabled by default.   If you
>   didn't have the privilege then **it wouldn't be listed at all**.
>   [Notice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379630.aspx)
>   that `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` is different from lacking
>   `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` or `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT`.

## Bonus Reading

- MSDN: [Privilege Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Technet: [Shut down the system - user right assignment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960201.aspx)

Comment: Your group policy handled by the domain will override your local group policy.  Adjust the domain permissions instead of the local permissions.  When you ran, "whoami /priv:, what user group were you in?  If I have completely not understood what you are asking, edit your question, because I am only taking a wild guess what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking why i am able to shutdown the system when my security token does not have the privilege. Whether the privilege comes from the local machine or the domain controller: either way i don't have it.

Comment: Removing the power plug gets around all privilege issues... :) Of course depends on how it restarts...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have the permission, but it is **disabled**. That's what PowerShell is telling you.

To shutdown system you use the Win32API function called [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna) or [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex):

```
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_POWEROFF, 0);
```

These functions note:

> To shut down the local computer, the calling **thread** must have the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege. By default, **users can enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME** privilege on the computer they are logged onto, and administrators can enable the SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on remote computers.

As you can see, Windows checks *thread* privileges (any thread has token with privileges). If you call `ExitWindowsEx` without the **SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME** privilege, the function will fail with the error:

```
Error code: 1314
A required privilege is not held by the client
```

Threads that you create by default inherit your privileges; but a program can enable a disabled privilege that it has been granted using [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/how-to-shut-down-the-system):

```
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, "SeShutdownPrivilege");
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

HANDLE processToken = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES);
AdjustTokenPrivileges(processToken, FALSE, &tp, 0, NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(processToken);
```

[Changing Privileges in a Token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/changing-privileges-in-a-token) says:

> `AdjustTokenPrivileges` **cannot add or remove privileges** from the token. It can **only enable existing privileges that are currently disabled** or disable existing privileges that are currently enabled

---

So, why is this privilege disabled by default? To make sure that no program can shut down Windows by accident. Applications should ask for this explicitly.

There is an ancient but very good book: [https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Security-Keith-Brown/dp/0201604426/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604426) about all that stuff.

Comment: I actually bought that book a couple of years ago; i'll have to give it a re-read.

Comment: If you know C you can download VS community (which is free) and try to shut down PC programmatically with out of priv. Then, enable this priv programatically and try again). It is the best way to study anything about Windows:)

Comment: @user996142 - what, by shutting it down?  Guess you're right. :)

Answer (score 6):

It's because your user belongs to a group that has that privilege enabled.

To see for yourself which group(s):

- Open a PowerShell (or Command) prompt as Admin.
- Run `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg OUTFILE.CFG`.
- View the contents of OutFile.cfg in Notepad or alike, and look for the `SeShutdownPrivilege` entry.  You will (should) see a couple/few SIDs for users and/or groups that have that privilege enabled.

So I have three short SIDs listed.  Short SIDs are usually computer-level accounts/groups. For example, one of them is `S-1-5-32-545`.

Using PowerShell we can determine which account/group that SID represents:

```
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ("S-1-5-32-545")
$objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
```

This returns `BUILTIN\Users`.

Since you're a user on that computer, you're automatically a member of that group, meaning you can shut down the computer.

The other two I have are `S-1-5-32-544`, and `S-1-5-32-551`.  These are the standard `BUILTIN\Administrators` group, and the `BUILTIN\Backup Operators` group.  Which line up with the groups you're seeing in the `secpol.msc` dialog.